# expand title bars into documents in Adobe Reader on OS X

Tags: macos, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader tends to turn all of my open pdf documents into title bars after my laptop computer (OS X) goes to sleep or switch screens. I wonder if there is a way to either suppress this behavior, or expand all of them to display the full documents without having to do this for them individually (for some reason I find myself having about 15+ documents open at any time)... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in OS X `Preview.app` to view pdf documents instead. There's generally been no need to install `Acrobat Reader` on recent OS X's.

Comment: Thanks! I do like Preview, but I didn't like its scrolling behavior (especially how it jumps between pages) and the increments by which the document would zoom when I pressed Command+ and Command-, so I switched to Reader. But otherwise, it's a fine program...

Comment: BTW, you can change the defaults for Preview's scrolling behavior: Single Page, Single Page Continuous, Two Pages, and Two Page Continuous.

Comment: Oh right... I think I did figure that out later... and I had added a field in the toolbar to enter the zooming factor directly but I still relied on the Command+ and Command-, which was still too coarse (very minor, I know). That was something I haven't been able to figure out how to change... otherwise, I really would switch back!